# How to get text-overflow to work with table <td> tag

Tags: html, css

I have a table with user names in a  tag. I need the table to be responsive and to be able to handle long usernames. As the table shrinks I need the first and last name to wrap, but then as it continues to shrink I would like to show an ellipsis as the names start to get cut off. I am struggling to make this work.

How do I get the user column to shrink in a responsive way and how do I get the text to behave as I described above?

```css
.leaderboard {
  max-width: 800px;
}

.media-left, .media-body {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.media-left {
  padding-right: 10px;
}

td a {
  padding: 5px;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

.user-column {
  max-width: 225px;
}

.leaderboard .name {
  display: inline-block;
}

.truncate {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0-rc1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0-rc1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table id="user-leaderboard" class="leaderboard table table-condensed">
  <colgroup><col>
  <col>
  <col width="22%">
  <col width="22%">
  <col width="22%">
  </colgroup><thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="text-center">Rank</th>
      <th>User</th>
      <th class="text-center">dataset1 </th>
      <th class="text-center">dataset2 </th>
      <th class="text-center">dataset3 </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="user-rows">
      <tr class="clickable-row" id="">
    <td class="text-center"><a href="#">1</a></td>
    <td class="user-column">
      <a href="#">
        <div class="media">
          <div class="media-left media-middle">
            <img class="img-rounded" src="http://twemoji.maxcdn.com/36x36/1f47e.png" width="36px">
          </div>
          <div class="media-body media-middle">
            <div class="name truncate">First</div>
            <div class="name truncate">Last</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </td>
    <td class="text-center sort-column"><a href="#">6</a></td>
    <td class="text-center "><a href="#">9</a></td>
    <td class="text-center "><a href="#">3</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="clickable-row" id="leaderboard-user-row">
    <td class="text-center"><a href="#">2</a></td>
    <td class="user-column">
      <a href="#">
        <div class="media">
          <div class="media-left media-middle">
            <img class="img-rounded" src="http://twemoji.maxcdn.com/36x36/1f47e.png" width="36px">
          </div>
          <div class="media-body media-middle">
            <div class="name truncate">Reallyreallyrealylreallylongfirstname</div>
            <div class="name truncate">Reallyreallyreallyreallyreallylonglastname</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </td>
    <td class="text-center sort-column"><a href="#">4</a></td>
    <td class="text-center "><a href="#">3</a></td>
    <td class="text-center "><a href="#">3</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="clickable-row" id="">
    <td class="text-center"><a href="#">3</a></td>
    <td class="user-column">
      <a href="#">
        <div class="media">
          <div class="media-left media-middle">
            <img class="img-rounded" src="http://twemoji.maxcdn.com/36x36/1f47e.png" width="36px">
          </div>
          <div class="media-body media-middle">
            <div class="name truncate">Firstname</div>
            <div class="name truncate">Lastnamelong</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </td>
    <td class="text-center sort-column"><a href="#">3</a></td>
    <td class="text-center "><a href="#">2</a></td>
    <td class="text-center "><a href="#">3</a></td>
  </tr>
  
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/929sy6jd/)

Comment: Just move `max-width: 225px;` from `.user-column` to `truncated`.

Comment: @ezakto this looks close, but I want the user column to shrink on window resize in a responsive way similar to the dataset columns. How can I make this happen?

Comment: The column would shrink until table headings can't shrink anymore. Try changing "dataset" headers to a single letter and resizing the window again. It'll do a bit more. There is no "responsive way" to handle every table. The common way is to add a horizontal scroll to the table when the viewport is too narrow.

Comment: Btw, that's because you add some sizing to the columns, so the table will shrink as long as it can mantain your requirements (in this case, the 22%-width columns).

Comment: @ezakto Well the 22% are only for the dataset columns. I don't have anything set for the user column. If I change "user" to "u" I don't notice any difference. The heading is not taking up much space so I don't understand why all the data below it is unable to shrink.

Comment: If the dataset columns are 22%, it's implicit that the rest is 34%. If dataset columns can get any smaller, then the rest of the table won't either (because, again, they will maintain their explicit and implicit proportions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing. I used some of the info from the other answers but I needed additional tweaks to make it behave how I wanted.

I think the most important things were getting rid of `display: table-cell` and using `display: flex` instead. Also to get the cell to shrink beyond the width of the contents I had to set `max-width` on the `<td>`.

This is what I ended up with.

```css
.text-center {
  width: 15%;
}

.media-left,
.media-body {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.contents {
  display: flex;
}

.avatar,
.name,
.full-name {
  display: inline-block;
}

td {
  max-width: 100px;
  min-width: 100px;
}

.media-left {
  padding-right: 10px;
}

td a {
  padding: 5px;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

.leaderboard .name {
  display: inline-block;
}

.truncate {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0-rc1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0-rc1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table id="user-leaderboard" class="leaderboard table table-condensed">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="text-center">Rank</th>
      <th>User</th>
      <th class="text-center">dataset1 </th>
      <th class="text-center">dataset2 </th>
      <th class="text-center">dataset3 </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="user-rows">
    <tr class="clickable-row" id="">
      <td class="text-center"><a href="#">1</a></td>
      <td class="user-column">
        <a href="#">
          <div class="media contents">
            <div class="media-left media-middle avatar">
              <img class="img-rounded" src="http://twemoji.maxcdn.com/36x36/1f47e.png" width="36px">
            </div>
            <div class="media-body media-middle full-name">
              <div class="name truncate">First</div>
              <div class="name truncate">Last</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </td>
      <td class="text-center sort-column"><a href="#">6</a></td>
      <td class="text-center "><a href="#">9</a></td>
      <td class="text-center "><a href="#">3</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="clickable-row" id="leaderboard-user-row">
      <td class="text-center"><a href="#">2</a></td>
      <td class="user-column">
        <a href="#">
          <div class="media contents">
            <div class="media-left media-middle avatar">
              <img class="img-rounded" src="http://twemoji.maxcdn.com/36x36/1f47e.png" width="36px">
            </div>
            <div class="media-body media-middle full-name">
              <div class="name truncate">Reallyreallyrealylreallylongfirstname</div>
              <div class="name truncate">Reallyreallyreallyreallyreallylonglastname</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </td>
      <td class="text-center sort-column"><a href="#">4</a></td>
      <td class="text-center "><a href="#">3</a></td>
      <td class="text-center "><a href="#">3</a></td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set a `max-width` for the `.truncated`. Since they aren't being shortened, they'll automatically stretch to the full width.
https://jsfiddle.net/yak613/jsdwcox9/

```
.truncate {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  max-width: 150px; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the jsfiddle you posted has the data all out of alignment.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: The data under dataset1 is not centered under the heading. Same goes for each dataset heading.

Comment: Thatt's because you're using a Bootstrap class (I assume), `.text-center` to center the text, and I didn't load Bootstrap into the fiddle.

Comment: That looks better, however I would like the user column to shrink in a responsive way similar to the way the other columns shrink. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Use `@media` queries. I'm going to update the fiddle with them.

Comment: It only cuts it off now after the screen narrows to < 800px

Comment: I need the username column to slowly shrink down as the window is resized in a fluid manner, is this possible?

Comment: Not really. You'd be fighting against Bootstrap's framework.

Comment: I'm not set on using bootstrap I just need this tabular data to be styled in a specific way.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `.name` cells are actually extruding past the widths of the cells. What you need to do is give them a fixed width of 66.66% (two thirds):

```
.leaderboard .name {
    width: 66.66%;
}
```

I've created a new fiddle demonstrating this [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Obsidian_Age/qyyg540z/1/).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Your link didn't include the code you posted. I went ahead and made that change, but it doesn't quite work. You can see the rank 1 user's name is wrapping when clearly there is more than enough room for it to fit without wrapping.